# Trying to add animations to divs on their appearance and disappearance using React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, animation

Let me explain you the scenario,

- I have 3 links/toggle buttons (Link 1, Link 2 & Link 3) and 3 DIVS (Div 1, Div 2 &
  Div 3).

I am trying to add animations to DIVS,

- When I click on Link 1 above, Div 1 has to appear in center (Animation: Fade-In-Up).
- Similarly when I click on Link 3 then Div 1 and Div 3 should appear
  in center (Animation: Fade-In-Up).
- And also when I click on Link 2 then Div 1 and Div 2 should make way
  for Div 2 (Animation: Fade-In-Up) by moving towards their respective
  sides.

All the 3 DIVs has to be centered,

- And if I re-click on Link 2, then Div 2 should disappear by moving
  towards Y direction (Animation: Fade-Out-Down), and Div 1 and Div 3
  should come closer by moving towards each other and centered.

Kindly help me with this, struggling with this for so many days. Thanks in Advance. [Refer this image for better understanding!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hrMh.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this: https://codepen.io/MSanbira/pen/wvmKqNe

CSS section:

```
.div-section {
  position: relative;
  --total: 3;
}

.div-section > div {
  --size: 200px;
  --gap: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(
    50% - var(--size) / 2 - 
    (var(--num-selected) - var(--place) * 2 + 1) * (var(--size) / 2 + var(--gap) / 2)
  );
  height: var(--size);
  width: var(--size);
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: 1s;
}

.div-section > div:not([data-selected="true"]) {
  top: 250px;
  left: calc(
    50% - var(--size) / 2 - 
    (var(--total) - var(--place) * 2 + 1) * var(--size) / 4
  );
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using WOW js with HTML but haven't explored it on React

Try wow js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-wow

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).